# JAVA 1.8 and WebSphere 8..5.5.11 - Spring and Apache CXF compatible versions

Tags: java, spring, websphere, cxf, upgrade

We are upgrading our java from 1.6 to 1.8 . And WebSphere from 8.5.5.2 to 8.5.5.11. We are facing issue with the version of spring and apache cxf. We think Spring 4.1.9.RELEASE and Apache CXF 3.1.12 versions are compatible but not very sure.

need an expert opinion if the above mentioned spring and apache versions go along with Java 1.8 and WebSphere 8.5.5.11 . Please suggest if there is any other version of spring and apache cxf that needs to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a WAS Upgrade project and did a similar analysis. I think you are fine. Please see the links for more information.

**Java 1.8 is compatible with WAS 8.5.5.11**

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/278401/does-websphere-application-server-v855-support-jav.html

**Apache CXF 3.1.12 is compatible with Java 1.8 and Spring 4.1.9**

http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html (CXF and Java)

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/30-migration-guide.html (Spring and Apache CXF)

**Spring 4.1.9 is compatible with Java 1.8**

https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/25/spring-framework-4-1-6-released

Comment: "I think you are fine."  -- oh did you check by deploying Spring+Cxf  on WS855+java8 ?  The words "I think" makes this answer useless. [Spring+cxf on ws855 has some serious issues - that's how I ended up in this thread]

Comment: I know this is really cold right now, but has anyone managed to get this to work? I have a legacy system on my hands at the moment and I'm facing the same issues.